# building a autoencoder but model.fit crashes vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to learn autoencoder by implementing it but model.fit crashes my vscode when the batch_size or epochs is set at a high number. I can also see that my memory reaches 100% and vscode becomes unresponsive

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn import metrics

#define input and output
n = 19
fib = [1,1]
for i in np.arange(2, n+1):
    fib.append(fib[i-1] + fib[i-2])

x = np.array([fib])
y = np.array([fib])
print(x)
print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)
plt.scatter(x,y)

#building neural network
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim= x.shape[1], activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(x.shape[1]))
model.compile(loss= 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')
model.summary()

#model fit
model.fit(y,y, verbose = 1, batch_size = 4, epochs = 1000)

pred = model.predict(y)
```

Comment: Does this problem only exist in VSCode?

Comment: I just ran it in google colab and its running fine even with big parameters

Comment: I think i found the issue, for some reason when verbose = 1, the prints crashes my vscode but with verbose = 0, it runs fine... any reason to why that is?

Comment: Does it run out of memory when run in a terminal outside of VSCode? Google Colab isn’t your computer, so that’s not particularly helpful information.

Comment: Just ran the code in my terminal. It works with verbose = 1